# Ogre3D shows exception when starting program

Tags: c++, ogre3d

I'm trying to write game using Ogre engine. I had a lot of problems - GCC didn't compiled program because it didn't found OgreMain_d and OIS_d... I created symbolic links (I'm using Linux) to libOgreMain.so.1.7.2 and libOIS-1.3.0.so and GCC compiled my program, but... the program shows error:

`OGRE EXCEPTION(6:FileNotFoundException): 'resources.cfg' file not found! in ConfigFile::load at /home/m4tx/Programs/ogre_src_v1-7-2/OgreMain/src/OgreConfigFile.cpp (line 83)`

My code:

```
#define OGRE_CHANGE1 ((1 << 16) | (1 << 8))

#include "Ogre.h"
#include "ExampleApplication.h"

#if OGRE_PLATFORM == OGRE_PLATFORM_WIN32
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#include "windows.h"
#else
#include <iostream>
#endif

// Dziedziczymy ExampleApplication
class MyApp : public ExampleApplication
{
  protected:
  public:
    MyApp()
    {
    }

    ~MyApp()
    {
    }
  protected:
    void createScene(void)
    {
    }
};

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

#if OGRE_PLATFORM == OGRE_PLATFORM_WIN32
INT WINAPI WinMain( HINSTANCE hInst, HINSTANCE, LPSTR strCmdLine, INT )
#else
int main(int argc, char **argv)
#endif
{
  MyApp App;
   try
   {
     App.go();
     return 0;
   }
   catch (Ogre::Exception& e)
   {
#if OGRE_PLATFORM == OGRE_PLATFORM_WIN32
     MessageBox( NULL, e.getFullDescription().c_str(), "Exception!",
           MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR | MB_TASKMODAL);
#else
     std::cerr <<"Exception:\n";
     std::cerr <<e.getFullDescription().c_str() <<"\n";
#endif
     return 1;
   }
}

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

Please help.

Comment: Is there a `resources.cfg` file in your program's directory? The `ExampleApplication` class (or Ogre itself) apparently requires one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your hint is clearly in the error message.  The example framework for Ogre expects certain files to be available, such as `resource.cfg` and even `plugins.cfg`.  Make sure this is in the path, and that the media required by those resources is also available.

Comment: OK, but where to get these files? :)

Comment: @m4tx, they are in the media folder in the Ogre distribution that all the samples use.